# state.blogs is not iterable TypeError: state.blogs is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, mern

while using useState hooks on the home.js was working fine. But when i try to use 'useBlogContext'

i am getting the error: state.blogs is not iterable TypeError: state.blogs is not iterable.

note that i am using useContext hook with UseReducer.

Also Error on the console:

```
    react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <BlogContextprovider> component:

    at BlogContextprovider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:458:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

home.js

```
 import{useEffect} from 'react'
import Blogdetails from '../components/blogdetails'
import Form from '../components/form'
import { useBlogContext } from '../hooks/useblog'


 const  Home=()=> {

 const {blogs, dispatch} =useBlogContext()

  useEffect(()=>{
    const  fetchBlogs= async()=>{

      const blogPost= await fetch('/api/workouts')
      const res=await  blogPost.json()

      if(blogPost.ok){
        dispatch({type:'CREATE_BLOG', payload:res})
      }

    }

    fetchBlogs()
      
// eslint-disable-next-line 
  },[])

return (
    <div className="home">
    
    <div className="worksouts">

      {blogs && blogs.map((blog)=>(
          <Blogdetails key={blog._id} blog={blog}/>
      ))}
    </div>
      <Form/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

blogcontext.js

```
 import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";


export const  blogContext = createContext()

export const BlogReducer=(state, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'GET_ALL_BLOGS':
            return{
                blogs:action.payload
            }
        case 'CREATE_BLOG':
            return{
                blogs:[action.payload, ...state.blogs]
            }
            default:
            return state
    }

}

export const BlogContextprovider= ({children})=>{
 
    const [state, dispatch]= useReducer(BlogReducer,{
        blogs:null
    })

    return(
        <blogContext.Provider value={{...state, dispatch}}>
            {children}
        </blogContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

form.js

```
 import { useState } from "react"
import { useBlogContext } from '../hooks/useblog'

const Form = () => {

const{dispatch} = useBlogContext()
const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
const [des, setDes] = useState('')
const [error, setError] = useState(null)

const handle= async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()

    const blogs= {title,des}

    const res = await fetch('/api/workouts',{
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify(blogs),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
   })
   const jon= await res.json()

   if(!res.ok){
        setError(jon.error)
   }
   if(res.ok){
    setTitle('')
    setDes('')
    setError(null)
    console.log('new blog added',jon)
    dispatch({type:'CREATE_BLOG', payload:jon})
   }

   
}


  return (


    <form onSubmit={handle}>

    <input type="text" value={title}  onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}  placeholder="title" />
    <input type="text" value={des}  onChange={(e) => setDes(e.target.value)} placeholder="description" />
    <button>add</button>

    {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}


    </form>
   
  )
}

export default Form
```

useblog.js

```
 import{blogContext} from "../context/blogcontext"
import { useContext } from "react"

export const useBlogContext=()=>{
    const context = useContext(blogContext)

    if(!context){
        throw Error('exception occured in the context')
    }

    return context
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BlogContextprovider } from './context/blogcontext';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
 
    <React.StrictMode>

      <BlogContextprovider>
      <App />
      </BlogContextprovider>
    
  </React.StrictMode>
    
  
  
);
```

blogdetails.js

```
    const Blogdetails = ({blog}) => {
  return (
    <div className="workout-details">
        <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
        <h5>{blog.des}</h5>
        


    </div>
  )
}

export default Blogdetails
```

Comment: try doing blogs: [] in blogcontext.js file instead of blogs:null in useReducer as initial state. Else you need to check if blogs === null inside case 'CREATE_BLOG': . And if that is the case then you can just return blogs:[action.payload] instead of blogs:[action.payload, ...state.blogs]. If you still cant figure out what im saying i will provide the example below.

Comment: well blogs:[] did not work. if u could provide the example using my code will be great help

Answer (score 0):

Do below in blogcontext.js

So as per your commnt you are saying that the below code is not working.

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const blogContext = createContext();

export const BlogReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_ALL_BLOGS':
      return {
        blogs: action.payload,
      };
    case 'CREATE_BLOG':
      return {
        blogs: [action.payload, ...state.blogs],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const BlogContextprovider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(BlogReducer, {
    blogs: [],
  });

  return (
    <blogContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </blogContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

i.e, making assigning empty array to blogs for initial value. Now the reason I tol you to do so is that for initial value as null for blogs you can't do [...blogs] an it is like doing [...null] and thus the error.

I don't know why it didn't worked but here is another solution which I was taking about.

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const blogContext = createContext();

export const BlogReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_ALL_BLOGS':
      return {
        blogs: action.payload,
      };
    case 'CREATE_BLOG':
      if (state.blogs)
        return {
          blogs: [action.payload, ...state.blogs],
        };
      return {
        blogs: [action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const BlogContextprovider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(BlogReducer, {
    blogs: null,
  });

  return (
    <blogContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </blogContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: your first & 2nd solution provide error: react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. & talking about the blogdetails.js which a add to the original  post

Comment: I'm not sure why its giving the warning for key even though you provided the key in home.js. Check if blog._id is unique for each item inside home.js

Comment: it is unique as it stored in mongodb